# Keep Untracked File in Github

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

I have a github repo which is being used by many users, and assuming more people will join as the project grows. As everyone clones the project i want it to be seamless.

It is a python project, and i have a `.env` file for passing the env variables. The file has some variables and some credentials.

I want the `.env` file to be untracked as some of the credential fields are distinct for every user and if anyone changes it on local it will be pushed via `git add .`.

I tried using `git rm --cached` but it removes the file from the github repository.

The closest answer i got is using `git update-index --assume-unchanged .env`. But this command will work on local only, if anyone else clones the repository the file will still be tracked.

To summarize, I want to keep the file in the repository, but it should not be tracked by Git.

Any Help Is Appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a tracked sample file, i.e. `example.env` and instruct users to complete the variables with their values and rename to `.env`? This is the way many popular repositories handle this type of situation.

Comment: Are you looking for `.gitignore`?

Comment: That is a contradiction in terms. Cloning a repository means getting all the files that are tracked, and not any that are untracked. "Untracked" means that a file never makes it to upstream; that's the point of tracking. Also, this is not a Python question. Please only tag languages that are relevant to understanding and solving the problem - do not tag them simply because your project happens to involve them in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that this isn't something you can do with Git easily.

For example, if you add the file to `gitignore` and then `git add --force .env`, changes to that file will still be shown in `git status` (see e.g. [How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/2954547)). Git just is not set up to include a file in the repository but ignore changes/updates to that file. It's theoretically possible within the underlying data model, but Git itself does not support it.

However, a common workaround is to create a template or example `.env` file (e.g. `env.example`) that you instruct users to copy to `.env` when they first set up the project. You would track `env.example` in the repo, and put `.env` in `gitignore`.

You can even provide a `scripts/setup.sh` or similar that can do this for them. Here's an example that would work well with a variety of Python projects:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set +x

cp -nv env.example .env

pyenv install --skip-existing
pyenv exec python -m pip install -U pip
pyenv exec pip install wheel
pyenv exec pip install --requirement requirements-dev.in
pyenv exec pip install --editable .
```

Another option would be to *generate* the example file from a template in code:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set +x

if ! test -f .env; then
  cat > .env <<ENV
FOO=1
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USERNAME=dev
DB_PASSWORD=dev1234
ENV
fi

pyenv install --skip-existing
pyenv exec python -m pip install -U pip
pyenv exec pip install wheel
pyenv exec pip install --requirement requirements-dev.in
pyenv exec pip install --editable .
```

Comment: Adding comment for anyone who visits this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore?rq=1